Running out of workers in Hangfire
We use Azure Communication Services to send out email and SMS messages to the users. We have a EmailNotificationJob/SmsNotificationJob Hangfire job per message. We often exceed the limits of 100 emails per an hour and we've got the Hangfire jobs stuck in processing for an hour.

services.AddHangfire((serviceProvider, globalConfiguration) => globalConfiguration
    .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
    .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
    .UseRedisStorage(redisConnectionString, redisStorageOptions)
    .UseBatches()
    .UseThrottling(ThrottlingAction.RetryJob, 1.Seconds())
    .UseTagsWithRedis(new() { TagsListStyle = TagsListStyle.Dropdown }, redisStorageOptions)
    .UseApplicationInsightsTelemetry(serviceProvider));

services.AddHangfireServer((provider, options) =>
{
    options.Activator = new HangfireJobActivator(provider);
    options.WorkerCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 5;
    options.HeartbeatInterval = 10.Seconds();
    options.SchedulePollingInterval = 1.Seconds();
    options.Queues = new[] { "critical", "default", "notifications" };
    options.ServerName = Environment.MachineName;
});

backgroundJobClient.Enqueue<EmailNotificationJob>(x => x.Perform(new(notificationMessage.Email, notificationMessage.Subject, notificationMessage.Body), null));

...
[Queue("notifications")]
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 3)]
public class EmailNotificationJob
{
    readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public EmailNotificationJob(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

    public async Task Perform(EmailNotificationJobOptions jobOptions, PerformContext? performContext)
    {
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var emailClient =  scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AzureEmailClient>();
        
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jobOptions.Email))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Email address is empty.");
        }

        var content = jobOptions.Body.ToHtml();
        await emailClient.SendAsync(jobOptions.Subject, content, jobOptions.Email);
    }
}

public sealed class AzureEmailClient
{
    readonly ILogger<AzureEmailClient> _logger;
    readonly string _sender;
    readonly EmailClient _emailClient;

    public AzureEmailClient(ILogger<AzureEmailClient> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _sender = configuration[ConfigurationKeys.AzureCommunicationServicesFromEmail];
        _emailClient = configuration.CreateEmailClient();
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(string subject, string htmlContent, string recipient, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("{ClientName}: Initiating sending of an email to {Recipient} with subject: {Subject}",
                nameof(AzureEmailClient), recipient, subject);
            
            var emailSendOperation = await _emailClient.SendAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, _sender, recipient, subject, htmlContent, null, cancellationToken);
            
            var operationId = emailSendOperation.Id;
            _logger.LogInformation("{ClientName}: Email Sent. Status = {Status}. Operation ID = {OperationId}",
                nameof(AzureEmailClient), emailSendOperation.Value.Status, operationId);
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("{ClientName}: Email send operation failed with error code: {ErrorCode}, message: {Message}",
                nameof(AzureEmailClient), ex.ErrorCode, ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}

The issue we've been seeing is that workers will pick up the low priority items from the "notifications" queue and then the jobs are stuck in processing for an hour (due to rate limiting on Azure but ignore that fact for now). In the mean time, "critical" jobs are put on the critical queue but they cannot be worked on because all the workers are occupied.
Should we increase the amount of workers, or how do we work around this issue?

Can you show the code where you call Azure? Maybe you could try actively checking for a rate limit condition coming from Azure, and then enqueue a brand new item into Hangfire for a time in the future. This will free-up the Hangfire processor to do something else. Having said that, it looks like there are lots of nuances around using Hangfire's UseThrottling so maybe you just need to configure some additional options. https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/throttling.html

@AndrewB, I've just added the code to the question.
